# Android app test with different API

Tags: android

I have an app which target is from 3.0 to 4.3. API. When I test my app to 2.2 from PC, eclipse runs another emulator which target is greater. When I change my app's preporties to 2.2 then I get many eroors so I can not test my app from 2.2 emulator. When I test my app from 2.2 device everything is just okei. I am litle bit confused about what is going on with my app.

When I change target to 2.2 I get errors in this line. In (HONEYCOMB and addAll):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    adapter.addAll(reminders);
```

Then I get error in this(isEmpty):

```
if (editTextDescription.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

And then when I extend this `PreferenceFragment` : I think I can add Sherlock to get this right am i correct about PreferenceFragment.?

But I do not get why I have so many errors in pc and in device my app work great..!?

Answer (score 1):

`Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` is not defined in 2.2 so you would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

> But I do not get why I have so many errors in pc and in device my app
>   work great..!?

I don't think your app works in 2.2 if it gives error when you change to target 2.2. Is the device running 2.2? What does the Android version in the device says?

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
```

This constant means Android 3.0 and as such it does not exist in 2.2 (there was no Android 3.0 when 2.2 was released).

```
adapter.addAll
```

I don't know what type is `adapter` but if it shows an error this means this call is not available in 2.2. If this is a List, then you're compiling with Java 5 API. Switch to Java 6.

```
if (editTextDescription.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

If `String#isEmpty()` shows error, then you're compiling with Java 5 API. Switch to Java 6.